# How can I have 2 different working AuditorAware implementations on Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, audit

I have two different datasources on my Spring Boot 2.6 project, but I'd like to have two different `AuditorAware` implementations (one for each datasource).

As you know, you can only have one `@EnableJpaAuditing` annotation in the project, and in there you can make reference to only one `AuditorAware` bean:

```
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef="auditorAwareImplBean")
```

I need to have for one datasource DB entities a `getCurrentAuditor()` implementation that returns a name and for the second datasource an `getCurrentAuditor()` that returns an email.

I've tried creating another `AuditorAware` implementation and then setting the `@EnableJpaAuditing` annotation on each `Datasource` config, but I get a duplicated bean error (you can only have one `@EnableJpaAuditing` per project.
The audit fields are on a separate `@MappedSupeclass` from all my entities, and the audited fields are annotated with `@Createdby` and `@LastModifiedBy`.

I don't want to change this approach (changing entities and so). Is there any approach you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible. After some research online, I ended up at Vlad Mihalcea's article on [emulating JPA auditing using Hibernate generator utility](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-emulate-createdby-and-lastmodifiedby-from-spring-data-using-the-generatortype-hibernate-annotation/). It's easy to implement with high degree of customization.

P.S. there are a lot of changes on the library which deprecates some of its annotations, including `@GeneratorType` used in the Vlad Mihalcea's article. I'm suggesting reading the Javadoc of the interfaces.